# Script to delete folders and files

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am looking for a simple script to delete folders and files. Everything I have seen online tells me how to delete files after 30 days. However I am looking for something that will delete folders as well as files older than 30 days. I am not familiar with writing scripts at all, I just know about the windows forfiles and how that can be used with this. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Will this give you a head start? It identifies directory entries over 30 days old then does an RMDIR if it is a directory and a DEL if is just a file.

```
forfiles /D -30 /C "cmd /C IF @isdir EQU TRUE (ECHO RMDIR /S /Q @file) ELSE (ECHO DEL @file")
```

Admittedly, I have not run this command to actually delete directories or files. This command only prints out the command that could be run. Please check each one manually before removing the `ECHO` from the command.